# Add hover and thumbnail support with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code I'm using: http://plnkr.co/edit/qfL6mg3bUGYxX70dx1WV?p=preview

I'm trying to figure out how I can pause the slideshow when a user hovers over the large slider image and also, if the user clicks on a thumbnail how can I add the "selected" class like the first image with the blue border has?

Here is the html:

```
<div id="slider-container">
      <ul class="slider">
          <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=1">
              <div class="img-caption">
                  <h2>Test1</h2>
                  <p>Test 1 text</p>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=2">
            <div class="img-caption">
                  <h2>Test2</h2>
                  <p>Test 2 text</p>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=3">
              <div class="img-caption">
                  <h2>Test3</h2>
                  <p>Test 3 text</p>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=4">
              <div class="img-caption">
                  <h2>Test4</h2>
                  <p>Test 4 text</p>
              </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <!--/main slider slider-->

      <!-- thumb navigation slider -->
      <div id="slider-thumbs">
          <!-- thumb navigation slider items -->
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li> <a class="selected">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=1">
            </a></li>
            <li> <a>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=2">
            </a></li>
            <li> <a>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=3">
            </a></li>
            <li> <a>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=4">
            </a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider-container {
    float: left;
}
.slider {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
.slider li {
    display: none;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.img-caption {
    background-color: #e3e4e4;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-top: -100px;
    padding: 0px 0 0px 15px;
}
.img-caption h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.img-caption p {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.list-inline {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.list-inline>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
}
.selected img {
    border: 3px #0084d9 solid;
}
#slider-thumbs {
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

And JS:

```
jQuery(function($) { 

  var $slider = $('.slider');
  var $slide = 'li';
  var $transition_time = 0;
  var $time_between_slides = 4000;

  function slides(){
    return $slider.find($slide);
  }

  slides().fadeOut();


  slides().first().addClass('active');
  slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

  $interval = setInterval(
    function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);


      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1;

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
    , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 

  );

});
```

If you  have any question let me know before down voting.  I'll do my best for clarification.  Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do : http://plnkr.co/edit/X2I1AFo2O1KOnnnBMiUg?p=preview

1. Thumbs are selected as slides are activated.
2. On user click thumbs are selected and same slide is activated.
3. On hover no action. (Thom-x's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25023277/3603806))

   $("#slider-thumbs li a").click(function() {

   ```
       var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

       slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');

       slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

       var $j = $thumbs.find('li a.selected').parent().index();
       thumbslist().eq($j).removeClass('selected');

       $j = $(this).parent().index();
       slides().eq($j).fadeIn($transition_time);
       slides().eq($j).addClass('active');

       $(this).addClass("selected");
     });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I used :

```
 $(".slider").hover(callback,callback)
```

Now you can pause the slider.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Qe3qq6v5g2FU3dVerUMc?p=preview

Edit : 
Everything is working now (with some basic Jquery functions).

Comment: This is awesome, simple, and perfect.  Any ideas on how to carry the selected class for the current image displayed?  I really appreciate your help.